# unable to save crontab file using CLI

Tags: linux, cron, centos

I am new to linux centos ,i am trying to save and exit crontab in centos.

I have used CLI.

```
  crontab -e
```

when i press esc key from my keyboard it says ":quit to exit: and i press ":quit" and press enter key from keyboard crontab exit without saving.

Comment: You may want to use another editor. For example, you can use `EDITOR=gedit crontab -e` to edit crontab with gedit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set vi as your default crontab editor using the command.
export EDITOR=vi

Then you can save and exit crontab using :wq.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you edit your crontab in `vim`. Use `:x` to save and quit at the same time. Details: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Saving_a_file.